# Using Vector Asset Android for different sizes

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I am creating a vector drawable.xml file. But my query is how will this xml will cater to images of sizes that were used for different resolutions? I am not mentioning the size of the view in my xml. Please clarify.

Comment: Vectors are mathematical equations so they are automatically calculated for different screen sizes

Comment: I am not mentioning any width and height for a vie win layout and i want the same image to shown in different sizes depending on device resolutions. Earlier we uses images of different sizes for different resolutions but using vector assets limit this requirement.

Comment: android will calculate the size of your vector drawable based on device resolution and it will set it to your layout or image view accordingly.

Comment: ok so did you try to create a `VectorDrawable` and set it a a `View`'s background or `ImageView`'s image drawable? if so, what are your concerns?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between `bitmaps` and `vectors`. The latter ones are scalable (without loosing details) because they are calculated using geometrical formulas, rather than being hardcoded in pixels.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set a vector to an image view and settings its width and height to wrap content. If we create vector drawable then a single drawable will be created and we won't have same image of different resolutions,Though the vector could scale up and down, but since i haven't mentioned the image view's height and width my requirement of the image to look slightly large in bigger devices fails just as we have for launcher icons.

Answer (score 1):

You Won't be needing to specify any size it will count mathematically try to go through these [link](https://thenewstack.io/vector-images-come-android-devs-need-know/) you will understand the whole  thing

Comment: The images are displayed in Android depending on the image sizes that we mention for different resolutions. We generally don't specify a width and height for a view in our layouts. So if we don't specify size of a view in layout and we create an image of size 20x20, 40x40,60x60 then different devices will pick the image accordingly and not from the view's width and height from layouts. This what's can't be done through vector assets

Comment: Yes but for that you will be using png image not vector assets